# Why the digits are being displayed using perl regular expressions?

Tags: perl

I'm using \D to not display digits but why the digits are being displayed using perl regular expressions?

Here's the content of the text2.tx file

```
1. Hello Brue this is a test.
2. Hello Lisa this is a test.
This is a test 1.
This is a test 2.
```

Here is the perl program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open READFILE,"<", "test2.txt" or die "Unable to open file";

while(<READFILE>)
{
   if(/\D/)
   {
      print;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take a look at what is going on behind the scenes. Your while loop is equivalent to:

```
while(defined($_ = <READFILE>))
{
    if($_ =~ /\D/)
    {
        print $_;
    }
}
```

So, you are checking if the line contains a non-digit character (which it does) and then printing that line.

If you want to print `Hello Brue this is a test.` instead of `1. Hello Brue this is a test.`, then you would have to use something like:

```
while(<READFILE>) {
    s/^\d+\. //;
    print;
}
```

Also, it would make for more readable code if you used a variable rather than `$_`.

Comment: thanks but you miss understood my question. My question is why my code is printing out the lines that start with a digit and it should not print those lines because I'm using the \D option.

Comment: If you want to skip the lines that start with a digit, then you would need to add the '^' symbol to say that you are looking at the beginning of the line. (For example, using /^\D/ instead of /\D/ will look at just the first character instead of anywhere in the line and check that it isn't a digit.)

Comment: Correct, the ^\D works but why the \D does not work if it suppose to search the entire line?

Comment: So, what the \D is doing is checking if there is any character in your line that is not a digit. Each line in your example above has letters which it recognizes as non-digit characters, so it prints the line.

Comment: that does not make any sense, are saying \D means ^\D+$

Comment: `if (/\D/)` is not the same as `if(! /\d/)` which may be what you are trying to do.

Comment: zkhr, the updated the file to include non-digits lines and using your logic of /!\d/, no lines are being output. I'm wondering why the non-digit lines are not being outputed

Comment: So, there is also a difference between `if(! /\d/)` and `if(/!\d/)`. The first one is what I mentioned above. The second one is looking for a line that contains an explanation mark followed by a digit.

Comment: thanks again zkhr for clearing up my understanding of Perl's regular expressions

Comment: I did one more test. I edited the test data file (text.tx) and it now contains a row of only digits and using my original code (/\D/) it still prints out this line of only digits, why? I even added (/\D+/)

Comment: As ysth mentioned below, the newline at the end of your line counts as non-digit character.

Answer (score 3):

/\D/ just checks that the line has at least one non-digit character (including the newline...).  Can you explain what you *wanted* to check?  What output you were expecting?

If you want to only print lines that don't have a digit, you want to do:

```
if ( ! /\d/ )
```

(does the line not have a digit), not

```
if ( /\D/ )
```

(does the line have a non-digit).

Comment: I'm not expecting any output because those lines in the file contain a digit but prints out those lines anyway, why?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to reject lines that have a digit rather than match lines that have a non-digit (as you're doing)

```
while (<READFILE>) {
   print unless /\d/;
}
```

This will print each line *unless* it has a digit on it.